# Converting NULL DateTime to Integer returns 0 instead of NULL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In my below node.js code, I am trying to get a MySQL result, then convert it to json.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.fetchEnrolledJobList = (event, context, callback) => {

    const params = event.queryStringParameters;


    if (!params || params.userid == null || params.languagecode == null) {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    } else {
        const userid = Number(event.queryStringParameters.userid);
        const languagecode = event.queryStringParameters.languagecode;
        console.log("userid", userid);

        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

        if (isNaN(userid)) {
            var response = errorCodes.invalid_parameter;
            callback(null, response);
        } else {

            // Get the list of completed jobs
            const sql =
                'SELECT seller_job_invites.idseller_job_invites,\n' +
                'seller_job_invites.idjob,\n' +
                'seller_job_invites.iduser as seller_id,\n' +
                'seller_job_invites.idjob_status,\n' +
                'user.iduser AS buyer_id,\n' +
                'user.first_name AS buyer_first_name,\n' +
                'user.last_name as buyer_last_name,\n' +
                'user.profile_picture AS buyer_profile_picture,\n' +
                'job.idjob,\n' +
                'job.idjob_subcategories,\n' +
                'job.posted_date,\n' +
                'job.start_date,\n' +
                'job.end_date,\n' +
                'job.total_cost,\n' +
                'job.location_lat,\n' +
                'job.location_long,\n' +
                'job_room.idjob_room,\n' +
                'job_room.isseller_at_location,\n' +
                '(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT translations.word FROM translations WHERE translations.dtype="JOB_SUB_CATEGORY" AND translations.language_code= ? AND translations.fkey=job.idjob_subcategories) ,(SELECT translations.word FROM translations WHERE translations.dtype="JOB_SUB_CATEGORY" AND translations.language_code="EN" AND translations.fkey=job.idjob_subcategories) ))AS subcategory_name,\n' +
                '(SELECT job_status.name from job_status WHERE job_status.idjob_status=job.idjob_status) AS job_status,\n'+
                '(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT job_feedback.feedback_time FROM job_feedback WHERE job_feedback.idjob = job.idjob AND job_feedback.iduser = seller_job_invites.iduser) ,NULL ))AS seller_feedback_time\n'+
                'FROM peresia.seller_job_invites\n' +
                'INNER JOIN job ON seller_job_invites.idjob = job.idjob\n' +
                'INNER JOIN user ON job.iduser = user.iduser\n' +
                'INNER JOIN job_status ON seller_job_invites.idjob_status = job_status.idjob_status\n'+
                'INNER JOIN job_room ON job_room.idjob = job.idjob\n' +
                'WHERE seller_job_invites.iduser=? AND (job_status.name = "SELLER_AWARDED")';

            con.execute(sql, [languagecode, userid], function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                    callback(null, response);
                } else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        
                        result[i].start_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].start_date).getTime());
                        result[i].end_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].end_date).getTime());
                        result[i].posted_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].posted_date).getTime());
                        result[i].seller_feedback_time = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].seller_feedback_time).getTime());
                    }

                    var response2 = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
                        "isBase64Encoded": false
                    };


                    callback(null, response2)
                }
            });

        }
    }
};
```

The `seller_feedback_time` is NULL in some data I have. In database, it is in type `DateTime`. However, if it is null, what I get is `0` and not `NULL`. Why is this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] !!! of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: I would think you can start by ONLY posting `for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {result[i].start_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].start_date).getTime()); result[i].end_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].end_date).getTime()); result[i].posted_date = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].posted_date).getTime()); result[i].seller_feedback_time = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].seller_feedback_time).getTime());}` and an example result

Comment: Why would you think you would need Math.floor on the int returned from Date.getTime() ?

Comment: If you have a possibility of not getting a proper time from seller_feedback_time, then use something like `let date = new Date(result[i].seller_feedback_time)); result[i].seller_feedback_time = isNaN(date) ? "some other thing like null or 0" : date.getTime()`

Comment: @mplungjan The problem lies in Date, `new Date(null)` is Jan 1 1970.

Comment: so is new Date(0) - so change `isNaN(date)` to `date.getFullyear() < 2000` or something

Comment: @Teemu: I tried by checking for null inside of an if condition. then everhything was returned as strings.

Comment: It was a bit unclear, do you want to preseve the null dates as nulls, or filter them out?

Comment: @Teemu: I want to have the null dates as NULL. I do not want to filter them out.

Comment: Now the problem is, that you said "_everhything was returned as strings_", but the string "NULL" would had been parsed to "Invalid date" instead of `0` ... Anyway, I suppose you could do something like this: `... = Math.floor(new Date(result[i].seller_feedback_time).getTime() || null;`. That would put a live `null` to the data when the time is zero. If Jan 1 1970 is a valid date in the data, then I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @Teemu: This worked. Thank you. Please provide as an answer,